# How to make a conditional column with only the values of the true conditon, using formulas only?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Example]

I don't know exactly how to make this question, and I'm sure it has been answered before but I can't figure out the  terms to search it.

Basically, I want to make the columns on the right to contain every number associated with the colors above. Like the image I shared.

For example, I was using `=IF(B2=$D$2;A2;" ")`, to show every number associated with *yellow*, but that leaves me with blank rows everytime the criteria isn't met.

So how exactly do I do this?

Comment: Check [FILTER Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759). It's exactly what you need

Answer (score 3):

In `D3`:

```
=DROP(REDUCE("",D2:G2,LAMBDA(Φ,ω,IFNA(HSTACK(Φ,FILTER(A2:A7,B2:B7=ω)),""))),,1)
```

Comment: nice and minimal

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As an [user mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77132706/how-to-make-a-conditional-column-with-only-the-values-of-the-true-conditon-usin/77132764#comment135976871_77132706) the filter function also does what I was looking for. And It succeded for me.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can accomplish this output using the following formulas:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A2:A7,
     b,B2:B7,
     ub,UNIQUE(b),
     DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE("",ub,LAMBDA(x,y,HSTACK(x,VSTACK(TOROW(y),FILTER(a,b=y))))),""),,1))
```

---

Not sure about your **`Excel Version`**, however Non-MS365 users may use

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D3</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$7)-ROW($A$2)+1)/(D$2=$B$2:$B$7),ROW($A1))),"")
```

---

Formula needs to fill down and fill right accordingly as well as may need to hit the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode based on ones excel versions.

---

Comment: Oh! I was just posting same.

Comment: Cool Dada, you can do it with `MAKEARRAY()` also

Comment: MAKEARRAY was my first guess. But these are real nice solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As an [user mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77132706/how-to-make-a-conditional-column-with-only-the-values-of-the-true-conditon-usin/77132764#comment135976871_77132706) the filter function also does what I was looking for. And It succeded for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also this can be achived using small function together with if in older versions of Excel:

=IFERROR(INDEX($N$810:$N$815,SMALL(IF($O$810:$O$815=Q$810,ROW($N$810:$N$815)-809,""),ROW(A1))),"")

[image]

Hope it helps.